# Finagle client is not refreshing dns cache properly

Tags: scala, server, client, finagle, twitter-finagle

We are using finagle-client 22.12.0 to connect to the service on HTTPS. The client configuration uses the default InetResolver but it seems like the Finagle client does not refresh the DNS cache periodically and still tries to connect to the incorrect cached IP on records changes at the server resulting in ChannelClosedException.I am already setting the TTL to 10 seconds as (networkaddress.cache.ttl=10).

Is there a way to fix this?